# How to bind related table in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dataset

I have two tables, `options` and `items`. One item is associated with multiple options.

[image: table relationship image]

I want to display items and their options in nested `ListBox`s. The problem is that the inner `ListBox`s don't display things. I think maybe I didn't bind `ItemsSource` properly. How to bind it?

My attempt below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TaxAccessmentDataSet x:Key="taxAccessmentDataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemsViewSource" Source="{Binding items, Source={StaticResource taxAccessmentDataSet}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemsoptionsViewSource" Source="{Binding FK_options_items, Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox x:Name="listBox"ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource itemsViewSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander x:Name="expander" Header="{Binding name}">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource itemsoptionsViewSource}" DisplayMemberPath="name">
                </ListBox>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataContext of the inner ListBox will be a DataRowView that represents an item. For you to be able use data binding to display the corresponding options of this item, the item must expose a public property that returns a collection of these options. The DataRowView class doesn't so you can't do this in pure XAML.

But you could handle the Loaded event of ListBox and create a DataView for the options yourself:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource itemsViewSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander x:Name="expander" Header="{Binding name}">
                <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="name" Loaded="ListBox_Loaded" />
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox inner = sender as ListBox;
    if (inner != null)
    {
        DataRowView drv = inner.DataContext as DataRowView;
        if (drv != null)
        {
            DataView childView = drv.CreateChildView(drv.DataView.Table.ChildRelations[0]);
            //or drv.CreateChildView(drv.DataView.Table.ChildRelations["FK_options_items"]);
            inner.ItemsSource = childView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I find that `childView` is empty and `childView.Table` which is `optionsDataTable` is also empty. But my `options` table do have data.

Comment: You need to explain (post) how your data relations are set up then. You will of course need to set up a valid relation between your tables for this to work. Check the example on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.childrelations(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've just used the `optionsTableAdapter` to `Fill()` the `options` table. Now it has data, but the `childView` is still empty.

Comment: I think the relation is correct. I set up relations in SQL Server. Then I use `Add New Data Source` and include all tables.

Comment: My bad. After I `Fill()` the `options` table, it works. The items except the first all have options. I made a mistake to look at the first item only. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A `DataContext` of an item is no more the parent - it is already your item. So you have to change

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource itemsoptionsViewSource}" DisplayMemberPath="name">
```

to

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding items}" DisplayMemberPath="name">
```

This binds the items of the nested `ListBox` to the property `items` of an `option` like shown in your diagram.

Comment: This won't work since a DataRowView has no public property named "items" that you are trying to bind to...